# Change background Color in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibackgroundcolor

i want to change my application background change. My view name is `topNavVw` for change my application background color i used this code

```
topNavVw.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

but it's not working .

Thanks in advance

Comment: where you called ?. which method u called ? like viewdidload or anything else

Comment: @Ferrakkem you mean you have to change only first screen background colour right..

Comment: You're trying to change the background color of an UIView or an UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

in `viewDidLoad`, in the Controller class that you want to appear black.

If you want a specific view/button/label to have a black background then it is the same,

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

If it still doesn't work, use the view hierarchy debug (the button just before the arrow on the bottom of the screen, in the separation of the debug screen and code screen). There you will be able to see all your views and maybe you'll notice that your black view is behind another view that is not black.

Comment: Do you have another view hiding self.view? (you can check in the hierarchy debugger)